# Adding tags to ListView's TextView?

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, textview, android-viewbinder

I'm writing my church's Android app, and I'm trying to use a ListView as a launchpad to view sermons online. The LV populates correctly, but there are two TextViews in each list item that aren't populated by the cursor - they have the same text in each list item. (They say "play audio" and "play video" to be exact.) I needed a way to click each of the TextViews and be sent to a certain webpage. I'm trying to add tags to each TextView, but I'm getting a NullPointerException when I try to access them from my ViewBinder. The tags all have different values.

Does anyone know how I can assign tags to these static TextViews?

**SermonActivity.java**

```
  public class SermonActivity extends SherlockListActivity implements
        OnClickListener, ViewBinder {

    private Cursor cursor = null;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = null;
    private dbAdapter dba = null;
    private ListView listView = null;

    // Arrays
    private static String[] FROM = { "title", "scripture", "speaker", "mdy",
            "hour" };
    private static int[] TO = { R.id.sermon_title, R.id.sermon_scripture,
            R.id.sermon_speaker, R.id.sermon_date, R.id.sermon_time };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sermon);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        // Makes home button visible
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // Allows home button to be used to navigate up
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onPause();
        dba.close();
        cursor.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Setting up the database adapter
        dba = new dbAdapter(this);
        dba.open();

        // Getting the Cursor of the requested data
        cursor = dba.read("sermons", null, null);
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.sermon_list, cursor,
                FROM, TO, 0);
        adapter.setViewBinder(this);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        setTitle(R.string.title_activity_sermon);
    }

    /*
     * To dynamically change the time of day displayed as well as adding the
     * title and file tags to the play buttons
     */
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {

        // To set the sermon time
        if (view.getId() == R.id.sermon_time) {
            String time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("hour"));

            if (time.contains("AM")) {
                ((TextView) view).setText("Sunday AM");
            } else if (time.contains("PM")) {
                ((TextView) view).setText("Sunday PM");
            }

            // Adding tags for the title and file name to the "Play audio/video"
            // buttons
            ***TextView playAudio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sermon_audio);***   //This is the line that throws the NullPointerException
            playAudio.setTag(R.string.file_tag,
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("file")));
            playAudio.setTag(R.string.title_tag,
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));

            TextView playVideo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sermon_video);
            playVideo.setTag(R.string.file_tag,
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("file")));
            playVideo.setTag(R.string.title_tag,
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));

            return true;
        }

        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int id = view.getId();

        // Starting WebActivity with needed data values
        if (id == R.id.sermon_audio || id == R.id.sermon_video) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("file", (String) view.getTag(R.string.file_tag));
            intent.putExtra("title", (String) view.getTag(R.string.title_tag));

            String type = null;

            if (id == R.id.sermon_audio) {
                type = "audio";
            } else if (id == R.id.sermon_video) {
                type = "video";
            }

            intent.putExtra("type", type);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

**sermon_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sermon_thumbnail"
        style="@style/Thumbnail"
        android:src="@drawable/sermon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sermon_audio"
        style="@style/FeedBody"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sermon_speaker"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:text="Play audio"
        android:textColor="@color/link" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sermon_video"
        style="@style/FeedBody"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/sermon_audio"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sermon_audio"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:text="Play video"
        android:textColor="@color/link" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sermon_title"
            style="@style/FeedTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sermon_thumbnail"
            android:lines="2"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:width="0dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sermon_scripture"
        style="@style/FeedBody"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sermon_thumbnail"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:text="Scripture" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sermon_speaker"
        style="@style/FeedBody"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sermon_scripture"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:text="Speaker" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sermon_time"
        style="@style/FeedBody"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/sermon_speaker"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sermon_speaker"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Time" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sermon_date"
        style="@style/FeedBody"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/sermon_scripture"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sermon_scripture"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:text="Date" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Stack Trace**

```
 03-19 17:17:45.942: W/ActivityThread(21858): Application com.lakesidebaptist.lakesidelife is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
03-19 17:17:45.958: I/System.out(21858): Sending WAIT chunk
03-19 17:17:45.965: I/dalvikvm(21858): Debugger is active
03-19 17:17:46.161: I/System.out(21858): Debugger has connected
03-19 17:17:46.161: I/System.out(21858): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-19 17:17:46.364: I/System.out(21858): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-19 17:17:46.559: I/System.out(21858): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-19 17:17:46.762: I/System.out(21858): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-19 17:17:46.965: I/System.out(21858): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-19 17:17:47.161: I/System.out(21858): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-19 17:17:47.364: I/System.out(21858): debugger has settled (1300)
03-19 17:17:47.794: D/dalvikvm(21858): GC_CONCURRENT freed 186K, 3% free 10996K/11271K, paused 13ms+12ms, total 37ms
03-19 17:17:47.981: D/libEGL(21858): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
03-19 17:17:47.981: D/libEGL(21858): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
03-19 17:17:47.981: D/libEGL(21858): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
03-19 17:17:48.036: D/OpenGLRenderer(21858): Enabling debug mode 0
03-19 17:17:51.848: D/dalvikvm(21858): GC_CONCURRENT freed 230K, 3% free 11206K/11527K, paused 14ms+13ms, total 54ms
03-19 17:17:51.903: I/none(21858): SELECT * FROM 'sermons';
03-19 17:17:51.903: I/none(21858): 20
03-19 17:17:55.731: D/dalvikvm(21858): Debugger has detached; object registry had 995 entries
03-19 17:17:55.731: D/AndroidRuntime(21858): Shutting down VM
03-19 17:17:55.731: W/dalvikvm(21858): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4182e300)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at com.lakesidebaptist.lakesidelife.ui.Content.SermonActivity.setViewValue(SermonActivity.java:90)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:131)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:256)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:733)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1622)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2102)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1866)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1687)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-19 17:17:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(21858):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Nothing in that line should throw an NullPointerException...

Comment: `at com.lakesidebaptist.lakesidelife.ui.Content.SermonActivity.setViewValue(SermonActivity.java:92)` What is line 92?

Comment: I marked it in the code, but it didn't show up well. That's the line TextView playAudio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sermon_audio);

Comment: But that doesn't make sense, there is no variable on that line to throw an NPE... The timestamp is at least 30 minutes old, depending on your time zone, could you post a more recent LogCat?

Comment: The line number changed b/c I took out some comments, but the offending line is still the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the view that is supplied from the method and find the view on that, something like this:

```
TextView playAudio = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sermon_audio);
```

**EDIT:**

You may need to find the parent View first, then use findViewById on that, try something like this:

```
RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout)view.getParent();
TextView playAudio = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.sermon_audio);
```

Comment: It throws the same error... Let me post the stack trace of the code in my post.

Comment: @wisner Did you update `view.findViewById(R.id.sermon_video)` too?

Comment: Yes. The stack trace looks the same as what I posted above.